# How to use values of find_peak function Python

Tags: python, dictionary, scipy

I have to analyse a PPG signal. I found something to find the peaks but I can't use the values of the heights. They are stored in like a dictionary array or something and I don't know how to extract the values out of it. I tried using `dict.values()` but that didn't work.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
 
 data = pd.read_excel('test_heartpy.xlsx')
 arr = np.array(data)
 time = arr[1:,0]   # time in s 
 ECG = arr[1:,1]    # ECG
 PPG = arr[1:,2]    # PPG
 filtered = savgol_filter(PPG, 251, 3)

 plt.plot(time, filtered)
 plt.xlabel('Time (in s)')
 plt.ylabel('PPG')
 plt.grid('on')
```

The PPG signal looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqOTR.png). To search for the peaks I used:

```
 # searching peaks
 from scipy.signal import find_peaks

 peaks, heights_peak_0 = find_peaks(PPG, height=0.2)
 heights_peak = heights_peak_0.values()
 plt.plot(PPG)
 plt.plot(peaks, np.asarray(PPG)[peaks], "x")
 plt.plot(np.zeros_like(PPG), "--", color="gray")
 plt.title("PPG peaks")
 plt.show()
 print(heights_peak_0)
 print(heights_peak)
 print(peaks)
```

Printing:

```
 {'peak_heights': array([0.4822998 , 0.4710083 , 0.43884277, 0.46728516, 0.47094727,
   0.44702148, 0.43029785, 0.44146729, 0.43933105, 0.41400146,
   0.45318604, 0.44335938])}

 dict_values([array([0.4822998 , 0.4710083 , 0.43884277, 0.46728516, 0.47094727,
   0.44702148, 0.43029785, 0.44146729, 0.43933105, 0.41400146,
   0.45318604, 0.44335938])])

 [787  2513  4181  5773  7402  9057 10601 12194 13948 15768 17518 19335]
```

Signal with highlighted peaks looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqOTR.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heights_peak_0` is the properties dict returned by `scipy.signal.find_peaks`

You can find more information about what is returned [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)

You can extract the array containing all the heights of the peaks with `heights_peak_0["peak_heights"]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
# the following will give you an array with the values of peaks
heights_peak_0['peak_heights'] 

# peaks seem to be the indices where find_peaks function foud peaks in the original signal. So you can get the peak values this way also
PPG[peaks]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html), the `find_peaks()` functions returns a tuple consisting of the `peaks` itself and a `properties` dict. As you are only interested in the peak values, you can simply ignore the second element of the tuple and only use the first one.

Assuming you want to have the 'coordinates' of your peaks you could then combine the peak heights (y-values) with its positions (x-values) like so (based on the first code snippet given in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = electrocardiogram()[2000:4000]
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=150)

peaks_x_values = peaks
peaks_y_values = x[peaks]

peak_coordinates = list(zip(peaks_x_values, peaks_y_values))
print(peak_coordinates)

plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks_x_values, peaks_y_values, "x")
plt.show()
```

Printing:

```
[(65, 0.705), (251, 1.155), (431, 1.705), (608, 1.96), (779, 1.925), (956, 2.09), (1125, 1.745), (1292, 1.37), (1456, 1.2), (1614, 0.81), (1776, 0.665), (1948, 0.665)]
```